# Name that theorem: $G/\ker(\phi) \cong \bar{G}$ for epimorphism $\phi : G \to \bar{G}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Theorem 2.7.1 in *Topics in Algebra 2$\varepsilon$* by I.N. Herstein goes

> *Theorem 2.7.1.* Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism of $G$ onto $\bar{G}$ with kernel $K$. Then $G/K \cong \bar{G}$.

The preceding paragraph states that this is a *very important* theorem. Does it have a name?

Comment: The name's already been told to you, and indeed it's hard to exaggerate its importance, and *this* perhaps is what you should keep in mind more than even its name, since you're going to meet it *a lot* in algebra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_isomorphism_theorem) states that if $G,H$ are groups, and there is a homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, then $G/\ker\phi\cong\text{im}\,\phi.$

The theorem you state here is simply the special case of the FIT with $\phi$ an epimorphism (that is, with $\text{im}\,\phi=H$). Another nice special case is that when $\phi$ is a monomorphism (that is, when $\ker\phi$ is the trivial subgroup), then $G\cong\text{im}\,\phi$. Of course, the least surprising special case is that, when $\phi$ is an epimorphism *and* a monomorphism (that is, $\phi$ is an isomorphism), we have $G\cong H$.

Comment: I only have to add that certain times I have seen used the name Noether's First Isomorphism Theorem although it is not usual at all.

Comment: For example, Robinson refers to the three isomorphism theorems as "the Noether Isomorphism Theorems" in his book *A course in the theory of groups*.

Comment: Could such an attribution really be historically accurate?

Comment: @rghthndsd: Which attribution do you mean? (Note that, if you wish to ask somebody a question on a post that isn't theirs, you should "tag" them by putting @ in front of their username. You can only tag one user per comment, though.)

Comment: @Cameron: I was referring to user1729's comment. Surely this isomorphism theorem must have been in common use in the mid-to-late 19th century before Noether. Although perhaps it was only implicitly? Anyways, my question was more or less rhetorical rather than directed at user1729 which is why I did not tag them.

Answer (score 6):

See the [**First Isomorphism Theorem (For Groups)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem): you'll recognize your theorem as a special case of the more general First Isomorphism Theorem for Groups. Learn it and learn it well!

Answer (score 5):

It is a special case of First Isomorphism Theorem. Therefore, I don't think it has a different name.

Answer (score 4):

Its name is the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: It's a little adventurous, not to mention rude, to write "not correct" to a claim like this one, for which there are many, many different versions

Comment: @Ustun, you are **not** stating any truth: Robinson Derek in his "Introduction to Abstract Algebra", Rose's "A course on Finite Groups", Herstein' "Abstract Algebra", etc. call that the first isom. theorem, not a "reason to that". We should be more careful in these things because names, symbols, etc. change from country to country and even within asame country,I, for one, was taught by two different persons in the very same mathematics dept. of the same university this very same theorem under tow different names...go figure!